# How to modify pie-chart input variables?

Tags: python, pandas, pie-chart

my problem is the following: from the Titanic Kaggle dataset I plot a pie chart of survived males and females.
This is the beginning of the code I used to make the previous task (a simple chart of all females and males) and worked out fine.

```
males = (titanic['Sex'] == 'male').sum()
females = (titanic['Sex'] == 'female').sum()

proportions = [males, females]
```

Now I would need to do the same thing but only with survived passengers, which in the column 'Survived' have a value equals to 1, but I have literally no idea how to do that.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, use [`boolean indexing`](http://titanic.loc[titanic['survived'].eq(1),%20'Sex'].value_counts(normalize=True).plot(kind='pie')) with [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) passing `normalized` parameter, then chain on  [`.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) with `kind='pie'`:

```
titanic.loc[titanic['Survived'].eq(1), 'Sex'].value_counts(normalize=True).plot(kind='pie')
```